# mysql not using index on simple join

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I'm wondering why mysql is not using an index in the following query on table (visit_url):

```
> describe select sv.url from visit_url sv, result_query rq where rq.result_id = sv.result_id and rq.user_id = 'fred';
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vu    | ALL    | result_id     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                   | 506553 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rq    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 32      |           vu.result_id |      1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

My indexes are:

```
mysql> show index in visit_url;
+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| visit_url |          1 | result_id |            1 | result_id   | A         |      168851 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| visit_url |          1 | url       |            1 | url         | A         |      253276 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------- --+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

and

```
mysql> show index in result_query;
+--------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| result_query |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | result_id   | A         |     2718272 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| result_query |          1 | query_idx |            1 | query       | A         |      271827 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

visit_url has 506k entries, result_query has 2mil

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I meant visit_url has 506k entries

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your query with an explicit join separated from your where clause like this:

```
select sv.url from visit_url sv 
  join result_query rq on rq.result_id = sv.result_id
  where rq.user_id = 'fred';
```

Comment: I don't think that should make a difference. Even mysql knows how to treat old-style queries as standard queries.

Answer (score 0):

`result_query.user_id` is not indexed. So finding the row with that `user_id` would require a full scan of 2 million rows. Instead it scans 500k rows of `visit_url`, and uses the primary key to join with `result_query`. This way, it has to scan a maximum of 500k rows to find the requested `user_id`.